# Find a lower bound of the Maximal function of $f(x) = \frac{1}{x (\log x )^2}$ in $x \in (0,1/2)$.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Define $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x (\log x )^2}$ in $x \in (0,1/2)$.

Maximal function of $f$ is $$(Mf)(x) := \sup_{r>0} \frac{1}{m(B_r)} \int_{B(x,r)} |f(y)|\,dy,$$ where $B(x,r)$ denotes a ball of radius $r$ and center at $x$, and $m$ is a Lebesgue measure.

I tried to show that $Mf \notin L^1(\mathbb{R)}$. So I took a lower bound of $Mf$ like this:

Since $f(x) \geq e^2/4$ where $x \in (0,1/2)$,

\begin{align*}
(Mf)(x) &= \sup_{r>0}  \frac{1}{m(B_r)} \int_{B(x,r)} |f(y)|dy \\
& \geq \sup_{r>0} \frac{1}{m(B_r)} \int_{B(x,r)} e^2/4 dy \\
&= e^2/4
\end{align*}
Therefore, $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} (Mf)(y) dy \geq \int_\mathbb{R} e^2/4 dy = \infty.$$

But I feel some weirdness about my solution now and cannot find where I exactly wrong.
Does my solution make sense? If not, where is my mistake?

Comment: If $f$ is only defined on $(0,{1 \over 2})$ I presume the question should be if $M_f$ is in $L^1(0,{1 \over 2})$.

Comment: @copper.hat $f = 0$ if $x \notin (0,\frac{1}{2})$.

Comment: Then I do not see how you get the lower bound for $Mf$. You only have $f(y) \ge {e^2 \over 4}$ when $y \in (0,{1 \over 2})$.

Comment: You have $f(y) \ge {e^2 \over 4} 1_{(0,{1 \over 2})} (y)$. I think you can get a lower bound of form $\min(c_1, c_2 {1 \over x})$, where $c_1,c_2 $ are strictly positive constants (for $x \ge 0$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a general result on the maximal function which goes as follows: If $f\in L^1(\Bbb R)$ with $c:=\int_{B(0,R)}|f(y)|dy>0$ for some $R>0$, then $Mf\notin L^1(\Bbb R)$. This is, because for $|x|>R$ we have
$$
   Mf(x)\geq\frac{1}{\mu(B(x,R+|x|))}\int_{B(x,R+|x|)}|f(y)|dy\geq\frac{c}{\mu(B(x,R+|x|))}=\frac{c}{2(R+|x|)},
$$
and the expression on the right hand side is not integrable on $\Bbb R$.